# generating resources for each level of building

Tags: php

Is it possible to change this code into function without using a loop?

```
$start = 80;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $start = $start * 1.5;
    echo "level ".$i.": ".$start."<br>";
}
function generate($start, $level){
// some code
    return $start;
}
```

Comment: So after passing `$start = 80;` and `$level = 1;` to this function, you want it to return `120` without using a loop?

Comment: yes, I would like to, but I don't know if it is possible

Comment: It is, since it's just simple arithmetics.

Comment: Can you give me some example? I know it must be pretty easy, but I have no idea.

Comment: I can give you a hint: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php is all you need.

Comment: Well I have changed the code: function generate($start, $level){
 $start = pow($start, $level);
 return $start;
}
echo generate($start, 1.1); but it won't gives me the same result and I have to fill $level values like this 1.1,1.2,1.3

Comment: @dontHaveName, do you actually want recursion instead loop?

Comment: I just don't want to use a loop

Comment: @dontHaveName, and you just want $start returned? (no other echo-es)? Will starting point always be zero(0)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For level 1 you have:

```
$start = $start * 1.5;
```

For level 2 `$start` is result from level 1, so:

```
$start = ($start * 1.5) * 1.5;
```

This same as

```
$start = $start * 1.5 * 1.5;
```

And can be simplified to

```
$start = $start * pow(1.5, $level);
```

In the end your function should look like:

```
function generate($start, $level){
    return $start * pow(1.5, $level);
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, also simplifies it mathematically to OP !

Comment: this is not correct answer because the function not print in each level the level details!!!

Comment: I am understanding it as as getting resource value for desired level without looping through every previous level. If output for each level is required then whole question makes no sense, since loop is the best solution here.

Comment: But this is what @dontHaveName asked

Comment: So let him decide if this answer is helpful or not. I asked in first comment about desired return from the function and provided my answer accordingly, seeing his unsuccessful attempt to implement my idea.

Comment: This is the correct answer, function should print only 1 level.

Comment: @dontHaveName Next time, please make it clear what should the function return or the output. As your question stands, you wanted to "convert" the "loop" to a function, this implies that the function should echo the result, and not return a *single* value.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to get the same result(include the level print to screen) you can use this code:

```
function generate2($start, $from,$to){
if($from==$to+1)
    return 1.5;
$tmp=$start*1.5;
echo "level ". ($from).": ".$tmp."<br>";
return 1.5*generate2($tmp,$from+1,$to);
}
```

**Or this:**

```
<?php
define ("MAX_LEVEL",10) ;

function generate($start, $level)
{
  if($limit==0)
    return 1.5;
  $tmp=$start*1.5;
  echo "level ". (MAX_LEVEL-$level+1).": ".$tmp."<br>";
  return 1.5*generate($tmp,$level-1);
}
```

**Here some check code:**

```
 $start = 80;//<=================your code
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $start = $start * 1.5;
    echo "level ".$i.": ".$start."<br>";
}
echo"---------------------------- <br>";
generate(80,10);//<====================my code
echo"---------------------------- <br>";
generate2(80,1,10);
 ?>
```

if you not need the prints you can use very simple function:

```
function generate($start, $level){
    return $start * pow(1.5, $level);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, a solution without "visible" loop:

```
generate(80,10);
function  generate($start, $level){
    $i=1; // Just a var
    $array = array_fill(0, $level, $start); // create an array with $level elements, with value $start
    array_map(function($v)use(&$i){ // Loop through the array and use $i
        echo "Level $i: ".(array_product(array($v, pow(1.5, $i++))))."<br>"; // Some basic math and output
    }, $array);
}
```

[**Online demo**](http://ideone.com/bSDlR5)

> <sub>Note that you'll need **PHP 5.3+** since this function is using an anonymous function</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you need just to output $start:

```
function generate($start, $limit)

{

$start = $start * 1.5;  
echo $start."<br>";
if($limit>1)
return(generate($start,$limit-1));
}   
generate(80,10);
```

My question - how to properly echo $level, without third parameter (0, in this case which should be incremented, no decremented:))? :)

EDIT: I would like to know better solution which will do the same, with two args:

```
   function generate2($start, $limit,$base)
   {
        $start = $start * 1.5;  
        echo "level ".$base.": ".$start."<br>";
        if($base<$limit)
            return(generate2($start,$limit,$base+1));
   }   
   generate2(80,10,1);
```

And final edit:

```
function generate($start, $limit,$i=0)

{
$i++;
$start = $start * 1.5;  

echo "level ".$i.": ".$start."<br>";
if($limit>1) 
{

    return(generate($start,$limit-1,$i));

}
}   
generate(80,10);
```

as answer to my self. :) Please test it (before down votes:)), and let me know about issues... Oh, i see - OP wants just 1 result, LOL...
Question wasn't clear to me (and not just to me, it seems) :)

Comment: This is a weird recursive pattern.. what is returned when `$limit` reaches 0 ? :-)

Comment: @Frederik.L, did you tested it? However, i made some edits in first function -> 10 results shown... (not 11, as before:))

Comment: No I didn't (I'm not the one that downvoted neither), but I do think that the `return` keyword should return something at the end, which is not the case in this solution. Whenever `$limit` reaches 0, you break the recursive chain, hence returning nothing at all.

Comment: Nevermind :), OP actually wanted something simple (to echo/return one value), and i didn't realized it. I thought that he want to include function somewhere in code, and to call it when it is needed - rather than to make arrays (yes, function just echoes values)...